# svn merge from branch to trunk deleting files

Tags: svn, git-svn

I am trying to merge the branch to trunk in svn, but somehow it is deleting some of the files automatically, although I have checked they both are in update revision.

Below is the command I am using for the merge:

```
(Into trunk folder)
svn merge (http://branch location)
```

Could anyone guide me accordingly how to resolve this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it trying to outright delete them (in which case that's probably what happened in the branch), or _replace_ them (in which case the branch probably wasn't created properly, in case of `git-svn`, this usually means a _new_ copy of a file was created in the branch _without_ history).

Comment: Show **full history of files in question in branch**! Hint (use `svn log -v`)